# how to make validation more safe in wpf desktop app?

Tags: c#, wpf

In my wpf test program,I have a passwordbox,When user try to login and input a string to passwordbox,how to compare this string with encrypted password to validate user's identity and how to make the this process of comparison more safe.
And my confusion is: Should I decrypt password to plain text then compare with user inputed string directly,like use a equation to confirm  whether two variables are equal?  I personally think if I do it in this way more secure programming skills should be applied,what is this kinds of skills?

Comment: Store encrypted password in DB. Take input from user, encrypt it and compare two strings. Search StackOverflow for 'wpf passwordbox' for how to deal with passwordbox control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well .. when he types it in, it is in plain text ... but you shouldn't store them as text, you'll usually add a salt and hash them, and keep the salt.
Then you'll do the same with the input, and if both hashes match, you let them log in ...

Example:
Password: *BadPassword*
You then add a salt (you could use a set one, or generate one, google it up).
let's assume your salt is: *YummySalt*. you then pass passtord+salt to hashing method: `Hash(password+salt)`.

you'll get some hash, lets say : *oanuh835930notihaoneu340*

you save that in DB, and when the user enters the password, you generate the salt (or just use the fixed one), hash it, and compare that to the hash in DB.